# Ruby on rails session doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm using the session hash in rails, it works well only one time when the login action is done and it renders another page. The name of the user appears in that rendered page only that time, if I move to another page the name disappears. The section where the name of the user appears is in the layout.

Here is my session controller:

```
class SesionController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @admin = Admin.find_by({"usuario" => params[:usuario], "password" => params[:password]})
    if @admin then
      session[:usuario] = @admin.id
      session[:nombres] = @admin.nombres + " " + @admin.apellidos

      @usuario = session[:nombres]
      @titulo = 'Panel De Control'
      @panel_activo = 'active'
      render :'admin/panel'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

end
```

and this is the controller of the page that is rendered and not showing the name of the user:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def panel
    @usuario = session[:nombres]
    @titulo = 'Panel De Control'
    @panel_activo = 'active'
  end
end
```

Hope you can help me.

..........

I comented the line of CSRF protection like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  #protect_from_forgery
end
```

and now it works... any reason?

Comment: Lets see the view code.

Comment: it is in the layout and it's so large, but this is how I show the name of the user: <%= @usuario %>

Comment: How about just a relevant excerpt? Replace sections that are obviously not relevant with "..." and post the result.

Comment: Do you have an AJAX request which is hitting your app without passing a CSRF token? That'll trash the session.